# virtualbox installation through apt gets stuck on ubuntu 18.04 bionic beaver

Tags: virtualbox, oracle, vagrant

I am trying to install virtualbox package using the command:

```
sudo apt-get install virtualbox
```

this installs three packages; **virtualbox, virtualbox-qt and virtualbox-dkms**. But the installation does not complete and gets stuck in between while installing virtualbox-dkms:

```
selecting previously unselected package virtualbox-dkms.
Preparing to unpack .../6-virtualbox-dkms_5.2.10-dfsg-6_all.deb ...
Unpacking virtualbox-dkms (5.2.10-dfsg-6) ...
Selecting previously unselected package virtualbox.
Preparing to unpack .../7-virtualbox_5.2.10-dfsg-6_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking virtualbox (5.2.10-dfsg-6) ...
Selecting previously unselected package virtualbox-qt.
Preparing to unpack .../8-virtualbox-qt_5.2.10-dfsg-6_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking virtualbox-qt (5.2.10-dfsg-6) ...
Setting up libqt5x11extras5:amd64 (5.9.5-0ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libvncserver1:amd64 (0.9.11+dfsg-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.60ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-20) ...
ureadahead will be reprofiled on next reboot
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.23-1ubuntu3) ...
Setting up virtualbox-dkms (5.2.10-dfsg-6) ...
Loading new virtualbox-5.2.10 DKMS files...
Building for 4.15.0-22-generic
Building initial module for 4.15.0-22-generic
Progress: [ 70%] [########################################..................]
```

I was previously using ubuntu-16.04 and this process seemed to work.
Others are facing similar issue and have posted on [this](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2393436) thread.

i have no clue to get it to work. Any workarounds.

**thanks in advance**

Comment: Have you tried downloading from virtualbox.org and then installing?

Comment: yes. But it only installs virtualbox-5.2; virtualbox-qt and dkms don't get installed along with it

Answer (score -1):

turns out, disabling secure-boot did the trick. hence the question is resolved.

Comment: **Warning!** Self-answer!  VTC Q not A!

Comment: Many users have Secure Boot enabled for a very good reason (Example: Dual-booting with Windows). Are you saying that none of them can use Virtualbox?

Comment: You can keep Secure Boot on - search for MOK (Machine Owners Key) setup. I found this rather fiddly though.